# HID Connection to a remote device without SDP record

Tags: bluetooth, hid, bluez

To connect a HID profile to a mouse/keyboard, HID_CONTROL and HID_INTERUPT channel with psm 17 and 19 needs to be connected. We find information using SDP record for the HID and then we establish a L2CAP connection to connect on the channels.

Is there any utility in bluez which can help me in connecting a input device. My keybaord/mouse does not support SDP record so when i use dbus signals(connect to a input device), it fails. 
Are there any libraries provided within bluez with which i can connect to a device using BD_ADDR and PSM numbers without quering for device via SDP

Comment: Can other platforms connect to the device ok? MSFT Windows etc? Can Linux connect to it if not using D-Bus API? Even the HID Lite spec uses SDP so I'm surprised that the device you have doesn't have SDP.

Comment: I have not tested on the other platform, but as SDP is not supported, i doubt that it will work with any device. I tried with the l2test tool to confirm  PSM 17 and 19. Is there any API's available in bluez to make a connection instead of doing SDP and then L2CAP conn ?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible using HIDD utility available, though hidd utility also does SDP and then connects, i tweeked the code with removing of code for SDP search, after that it did connect on control and interrupt channels. As my peer device was capable of PSM 17 and 19, it did accepted HID connection